# Cannot convert value of type 'Observable<String>' to expected argument type 'BehaviorRelay<String>'

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Cannot convert value of type 'Observable' to expected argument type 'BehaviorRelay'

I am using RxSwift. 
I have

In VM.

```
        let St: BehaviorRelay<String>
```

In VC as Input

```
        St: self.searchbar.rx.text.orEmpty.asObservable()
```

How can I convert it? 
So, I can get

BehaviorRelay from searchbar. Make sure, its INPUT.

Answer (score 2):

You can use RxCocoa's `bind(to: _)` method for this.

```swift
class ViewModel {
    let inputText = BehaviorRelay(value: "")
}

class YourViewController: UIViewController { 
    private let viewModel = ViewModel()

    func viewDidLoad() {
        searchBar.rx.text
            .orEmpty()
            .bind(to: viewModel.inputText)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the simple answer and it looks much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Input and Output structs in ViewModel and pass the searchText as Observable to ViewModel via Input

```
    class ViewModel {

       private let searchText = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")

       struct Input {
         let text: Observable<String>
       }

       struct Output {
         let result: Driver<[String]>
       }

       func transform(input: Input) -> Output {
          input.text.bind(to: searchText)
          let result = Driver<[String]>.just([])
          return Output(result: result)
       }
   }
```

in ViewController

```
class SearchViewController {

    let viewModel = ViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      bindViewModel()
    }

    func bindViewModel() {
      let input = ViewModel.Input(text: self.searchBar.rx.text.orEmpty.asObservable())
      let output = viewModel.transform(input: input)
      //use output to show results
    }
}
```

Comment: This is simple, I could do. I mentioned, its input, means its not directly binded or subscribed to accept event.

Comment: You can pass the text to VM as input string and in input function it will be binded to behaviorRelay using accept

Comment: @SamShaikh updated the answer to pass the search text as Observable